# Obj-C - NSString that saves all input using currentTitle and UILabel.text methods

Tags: objective-c, methods, nsstring

```
  NSString* digit                  = [sender currentTitle];

if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber){ 
    NSString* currentDisplayText = [[self display]text];
    NSString* newDisplayText     = [currentDisplayText stringByAppendingString:digit];

self.display.text                = newDisplayText;
```

I´ll try and explain my problem as good as I can. This line of code here takes the digit from a selection of buttons, saves it no the string "digit". "currentDisplayText"takes the digit displayed in a label. Then these two strings are appended and sent to the "display" (label)

But there is also an enter button. Which clears the display (so user can enter new number ) this is a calculator btw!

```
- (IBAction)enterPressed{

[self.brain pushOperand:[self.display.text doubleValue]];
self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = NO;
```

What I want is to display a "history" label that displays all the numbers entered - I have not quite understood how I get the string I save the "history" too, to not reset like the display does. This might be bad exlained by me, but any hints are appreciated. I am still learning objective-c...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to save the number after pressing the enter button. For this you need to add an attribute of type NSMutableArray to your class. Then in the method  do:

```
- (IBAction)enterPressed {
    [myHistoryArrayAttrib addObject: self.display.text]; 

    [self.brain pushOperand:[self.display.text doubleValue]];
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = NO;

    //after this you can clear your display
    self.display.text = nil;
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understander you very well , but one thing I am sure , if you want save your data (not very large) , you should use NSUserDeafult . use `- (void)setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id)aKey;`to save the data.

You want to svae the history , if you want to save the lastest history , you could use `- (NSString *)stringForKey:(NSString *)defaultName;` to get the string which you save. and if you want to save the whole history , you could use `- (NSArray *)arrayForKey:(NSString *)defaultName;` to get the array which you save.

give an eg. how to save a string

```
                    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:theKey] == nil)
                    {
                        NSString *defaultValue = [NSString stringWithString:theStringYouWantedSave];
                        NSDictionary *saveDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:defaultValue forKey:theKey];
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:saveDict];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:theStringYouWantedSave forKey:theKey];
                    }
```

and get like this

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:theKey]!=nil)
{
    yourHistoryString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:theKey];
}
```